# Retaining colors while plotting multiple lines in a loop (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, plot

I'm plotting a changing number of line trajectories on a sequence of images. I want the lines to be of different colors (as much as possible), and I want the colors to be retained throughout the sequence.
My code right now uses one plot command (`plot(traj_to_plot{:})`) using a cell array containing alternating x and y coordinates for each trajectory (meaning `traj_to_plot={[traj1_x_coor] [traj1_y_coor] [traj2_x_coor] [traj2_y_coor] ...}`). The order of the trajectories between each cycle of the loop is not always retained, and the number of the trajectories can change, as mentioned before.I need some way of relating between the trajectory drawn in one frame to the same trajectory drawn in a consecutive frame, and if it stopped, I need the following trajectories to stay in the same color (not simply change according to the ColorOrder cycle).

Here's two consecutive images where a change occurs:
[image: 1st frame]
[image]

the problem is evident in these sample photos. Because ant number 2 wasn't recognized in the second frame, the color order cycle changed the color of most of the trajectories.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually assign colours to each plot as so:

```
figure();
hold on;

plot(traj_to_plot{1},'red')
plot(traj_to_plot{2},'blue')
```

and so on.

If this a repetitive task, you could use something along the lines of:

```
colours = {'blue', 'green', 'red', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black'};

figure();
hold on;

traj_to_plot1{1} = [1 2 3];
traj_to_plot1{2} = [0 2 4];

for ii=1:numel(traj_to_plot1)
    plot(traj_to_plot1{ii},colours{mod(ii,numel(colours))});
end

traj_to_plot2{1} = [0.5 2 3.5];
traj_to_plot2{2} = [-0.5 2 4.5];
traj_to_plot2{3} = [-1.0 2 5];

for ii=1:numel(traj_to_plot2)
    plot(traj_to_plot2{ii},colours{mod(ii-1,numel(colours))+1});    %Thanks to @wakjah.
end
```

[image]

Comment: +1 might be worth incorporating a `mod` to allow an arbitrary number of plots with the same colour sequence - i.e. `colours{mod(ii-1, numel(colours))+1}`. Edit: oh I see you've done this, but you still need the -1...+1 otherwise you will get an error when ii==numel(colours) :-)

Comment: This is actually not what I meant, because it doesn't take care of the changing of colors assigned to the same trajectory between loop cycles. `traj1` coordinates can be `traj 17` (or any other number for that matter) in the following cycle.
Nevertheless, I appreciate the effort.

I managed to solve this on my own, by alloting a specific color to every new ant (using hsv colormap) and keeping track of the trajectories identities throughout the analysis.